# the possibility of a breakwater/seawall preventing the beginnings of a landslide-formed tsunami

Tags: fluid-mechanics, civil-engineering, design, dynamics

. . A thought recently crossed my mind which I cant seem to find any studied material on. It occurred while hearing a story about a potential future landslide in Kauai causing a large tsunami aimed at Japan; similar to this July 2017 landslide in Greenland [[1]](https://www.nature.com/news/huge-landslide-triggered-rare-greenland-mega-tsunami-1.22374).

The story made me wonder, can a breakwater/seawall built around any potential landslide area prevent the future buildup of a tsunami; or maybe a significant portion of its energy transfer?

To clarify, I am **not** writing about defensive measures that articles mostly seem to speak of [[2]](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/asia/japans-sea-wall-storm-brews-over-plans-to-construct-giant-5bn-barrier-against-tsunamis-a6914781.html). Instead, I'm interested in preventative measures for controllable instances. Thanks for any insight.

Comment: It depends on circumstances at the the site: depth of water, amount of material in the landslide, the rate at which the material slides, the proximity of the seawall & its height, strength characteristics, profile. This question is very broad. For some sites it may be feasible, for others it will not be.

Answer (score 0):

As a minimum, you'd need a catch-basin roughly the volume of the anticipated landslide.  That is a very large volume.  But that's not enough.  The reason a tsunami wave is formed is that the landslide mass transfers most of its energy to creating a near-plane-wave front, which means there's not much directional dissipation.  And what that means is that your proposed seawall would have to be strong enough and mechanically designed well enough to force energy dissipation in the plane perpendicular to the direction of motion of the wave.  That's not going to be possible, basically.

*[if only what-if  were still active, I'm sure Randall would jump all over the numerical analysis here]*